# Two Fourier Series (and a conjecture !)

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

**(1)** I guess 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\cot(\frac{n}{2})\cos(nx)=\frac{x^2}{2}\;\; ;\;\; -\pi\leq x\leq\pi
$$
Is it true?

**Note.** If it is true, then also
$$2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\cot(\frac{n}{2})\sin^2(\frac{nx}{2})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\cot(\frac{n}{2})-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\cot(\frac{n}{2})\cos(nx)=\frac{x^2}{2}\;\; ;\;\; -\pi\leq x\leq\pi
$$

**(2)** 
Evaluate the following Fourier series
$$
2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\cot(\frac{n}{2})\sin^2(\frac{nx}{2})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\cot(\frac{n}{2})-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\cot(\frac{n}{2})\cos(nx)\;\; ;\;\; x\notin 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$$
(compare it to the above conjecture !)

Comment: From different sources, the Fourier series of $x^2$ has terms in $(-1)^n/n^2$. (Likewise, the sawtooth has terms in $(-1)^n/n$.)

Comment: The Fourier series of a square integrable function cannot have unbounded coefficients. Where that cotangent comes from?

Comment: i think that formula doesn't even converge.... because $\frac{1}{n*tan(n/2)}$ is no 0-sequence...... in fact i think it isn't even a cauchy-sequence
(maybe I'm wrong... but I seriosly doubt it...)

Comment: perhaps we need the hypothesis: "for all $x$ such that the series is convergent", e.g., for $x=0$, is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\cot(\frac{n}{2})=0$?

Comment: As proofen here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1461164/276000
this formula doesn't converge for x = 0 and i think with a little effort you could proof that it doesn't converge for any x. so  yes ;) for all x such that the series is converget it convergates.... against every function ;)